# ASP.NET Accessing Interface methods, query on how method contents are called

Tags: asp.net, interface

So I have an Interface as follows

```
public interface IMembershipProvider
{   
    bool GetUserGuidFromSSOToken(string ssoToken, out string userGuid, out int statusCode);
}
```

And a Class as Follows which Implements the above Interface

```
public class MembershipProvider : IMembershipProvider
{
    public bool GetUserGuidFromSSOToken(string ssoToken, out string userGuid, out int statusCode)
    {

       ....Method Contents
    }
}
```

And then in my Presenter I have the following

```
private IMembershipProvider Provider;

..

if (!Provider.GetUserGuidFromSSOToken(ObSSOCookie.Value, out userGuid, out statusCode))
```

And when this is called it use the code for the method from MembershipProvider class, but I am just wondering how that's possible when the MembershipProvider is never referenced in the Presenter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MembershipProvider instance must be injected into the Presenter using dependency injection.

Comment: Can you explain that ? So you mean MembershipProvider must be called somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, the MembershipProvider object, which is a dependency for the Presenter, is instantiated outside of the Presenter and then injected into the Presenter, either through it's constructor or as a property on the Presenter which can be set. The instantiation can be done by the programmer, or an Inversion of Control (IOC) container can be used to automatically wire up the dependencies and inject them. Search for *Dependency Injection* and *IOC Containers*

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of service factory provider is usually what I do.

```
private IMembershipProvider Provider = 
    MembershipProviderService.GetDefaultProvider();

...


internal class MembershipProviderService
{
    IMembershipProvider GetDefaultProvider()
    {
        return new MembershipProvider();
    }
}
```